# How to display UIView in fullscreen and rotate to landscape in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, ios10

I'm using `VIMVideoPlayer` pod for streaming video on an iOS 10 app and want to display it in *fullscreen* and *rotate the video to landscape mode*. The app itself is meant to work only in portrait mode. How is it possible to present the `View` on fullscreen and be able to switch back to normal video mode?

Comment: have you tried investigating this property? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations